How to enforce Skia to use float texture rather than half?
When I attempted to port a Metal shader from iOS, I tried rewriting the shader in SKSL and running it on iOS. The program compiles and runs, but there are some precision issues. After debugging with the Metal Debugger, I discovered that the problem arises because SKSL uses half for textures and samplers by default. Is there a way to make SKSL use float for textures and samplers when it ultimately compiles to iOS's MSL?

My SKSL looks like:
            uniform shader child;

            uniform float scale;

            uniform float imageWH[2];



            float4 srgbToLinear(float4 coord) {

                       ......

                       float4 color = child.eval(coord)


And the result in debugger:
kernel float4
srgbToLinear(texture2d<half, access::sample>  inTexture xxxx

        .......

        float4 p0 = float4(inTexture.sample(smp, coord))


